# ObjectCollectedException during Eclipse Conditional Breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

The Conditional Breakpoint says:

```
"String Literal".equals( stringWhichIsInScope )
```

The Exception in `.metadata/.log` is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.debug 4 125 2019-04-29 14:31:48.928
!MESSAGE Internal error logged from JDI Debug: 
!STACK 0
com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.MirrorImpl.defaultReplyErrorHandler(MirrorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jdi.internal.ObjectReferenceImpl.disableCollection(ObjectReferenceImpl.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIObjectValue.disableCollection(JDIObjectValue.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.engine.Interpreter.disableCollection(Interpreter.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.engine.Interpreter.push(Interpreter.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.instructions.Instruction.pushNewValue(Instruction.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.instructions.PushString.execute(PushString.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.engine.Interpreter.execute(Interpreter.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.engine.ASTEvaluationEngine$EvalRunnable$1EvaluationRunnable.run(ASTEvaluationEngine.java:705)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread.runEvaluation(JDIThread.java:840)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.eval.ast.engine.ASTEvaluationEngine$EvalRunnable.run(ASTEvaluationEngine.java:758)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.core.model.JDIThread$ThreadJob.run(JDIThread.java:3603)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

There is not much to go on here, to diagnose this. What else can I try? What can I examine?

Comment: Might be [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537399)

Comment: @greg-449  I tried the workaround mentioned in that bug report, but it appeared to have no effect :(